# Ruby attr_reader and +=

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

I have recently been stumped by the following code:

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :n

  def initialize(i)
    @n = i
  end

  def val
    n
  end

  def bump!
    n += 1
  end
end

f = Foo.new(0)

puts f.val
f.bump!
```

`puts f.val` succeeds and prints out `0` as expected. `f.bump!` causes the following `NoMethodError`

```
foo.rb:13:in `bump!': undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
        from foo.rb:20:in `<main>'
```

Any idea why `n` is `nil` in the expression `n += 1`?

Using `n = 1 + n` instead raises a `TypeError` (`nil cannot be coerced into Fixnum`), so `n` is in fact `nil`.

Comment: FWIW, I don’t think having attr_accessor used like that inside a class makes sense, maybe better just use @foo inside everywhere? Might be it is not even supported.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Even though you've defined an `n=` method for `Foo`, Ruby won't let you call it from *within* the class without an explicit receiver i.e. `self.n=`

So when you write `n += 1`, this gets translated into `n = n + 1`. `n=` doesn't have an explicit receiver so Ruby creates a local variable `n` (which is `nil`). Thus the `n` in `n + 1` refers to a `nil` local variable, giving you the `NoMethodError`.

FYI, you don't need `attr_accessor` unless you want `n` to be accessible *outside* of the class! Even then, when you're writing instance methods, you should just use the normal instance variable `@n`.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks! I wouldn't write something like this, just stumbled upon it while refactoring a class which does export accessors with a good reason.

Comment: I think it's also worth mentioning that the reason why Ruby requires a receiver is specifically to allow for local variable creation like this. Otherwise it would be impossible to create a local variable after the `attr_writer` was defined.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is there :

```
def bump!
  n += 1
end
```

Use `self.n`. Or `@n`.

When you do :

```
attr_accessor :n
```

In fact you do :

```
def n
  @n
end

def n=(value)
  @n= value
end
```

And when you do `n += 1`, you use a local variable (which is niL) instead of using the two methods that were created by the `attr_accessor`.

Comment: `@n += 1` and `self.n += 1` both work. This wasn't the question though. @Dominic: it is the reader part that fails, not the assignment.

Comment: Yeah I just figured it out. Thanks ;-)

Comment: > you use a local variable (which is niL)

**This** is the question. :-) Why is `n` `nil` inside `#bump!` and not `nil` inside `#val`?